# Deleting all lines matching a specific pattern by retaining the first line in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I want to edit a gtf file by deleting all the lines except the first line matching pattern 'FAT1' and modify the coordinates ( 3rd & 4th columns) .

```
#!genome-build GRCh38.p7
#!genome-version GRCh38
#!genome-date 2013-12
#!genome-build-accession NCBI:GCA_000001405.22
#!genebuild-last-updated 2016-06
1       havana  exon    137682  137965 gene_id "ENSG00000239906"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "RP11-34P13.16"; gene_source "havana";
1       havana  gene    139790  140339  gene_id "ENSG00000239906"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "RP11-34P13.14"; gene_source "havana"; 
1       havana  exon    140001  140101 gene_id "ENSG00000269981"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "FAT1"; gene_source "havana";
1       havana  gene    143401  145401  gene_id "ENSG00000269981"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "FAT1"; gene_source "havana";
```

expected output

```
#!genome-build GRCh38.p7
#!genome-version GRCh38
#!genome-date 2013-12
#!genome-build-accession NCBI:GCA_000001405.22
#!genebuild-last-updated 2016-06
1       havana  exon    137682  137965 gene_id "ENSG00000239906"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "RP11-34P13.16"; gene_source "havana";
1       havana  gene    139790  140339  gene_id "ENSG00000239906"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "RP11-34P13.14"; gene_source "havana"; 
1       havana  exon    147653  148000 gene_id "ENSG00000269981"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "FAT1"; gene_source "havana";
```

---

I tried some thing like this.

```
    # Keep only the unique entry for FAT1 gene. 
    awk '/"ENSG00000269981"/&&c++ {next} 1' ref.gtf > ref_edit.gtf 

   #then manually edit the coordinates in vim editor
```

But i'm sure there will be more reasonable solution.

Comment: What is the logic of modifying the 3rd and 4th column? Also please do add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RanvinderSing13 Edit 3 and 4th column to make a custom gtf file with new coordinates.

Comment: Sure, please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem and let us know then.

Comment: mine answer is  ready but waiting for your post's update, since we encourage all users to add their tried codes, so requested you to do so.

Comment: But those lines represent completely different entries: one is a `gene` and the other is an `exon`. For your overall entry to be valid (as a transcribed gene) you'll need both. I think this question will be better answered over on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I tried some thing like this. a) Keep only the unique entry for FAT1 gene.                                                                                                          awk '/"ENSG00000269981"/&&c++ {next} 1' ref.gtf > ref_edit.gtf    b) then manually edit  the coordinates in vim editor

Comment: @Kryo, Sure thank you for showing efforts, please do add them in your question itself. I have posted mine answer now, cheers. Note: Comments are not meant to post code, so please always add codes in your posts, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v new_fourth_col="147653" -v new_fifth_col="148000" '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
/gene_name "FAT1"/{
  if(++count==1){
    $4=new_fourth_col
    $5=new_fifth_col
    print
  }
  next
}
{
  $1=$1
  print
}
' Input_file
```

Also I have made your output as tab delimited.

Comment: @RavinderSingh..out of curiosity, what if i need to print the first two line if FAT1 gene is found more than 2 times?

Comment: @Kryo, yeah we could do so too. I will read Input_file 2 times, in 1st time read I will create an array which has count of FAT1 and then in second read of Input_file ACT accordingly. IMHO in single read it  will be more complex, you could give it a shot, lemme know if any queries please.